# Lucas paper (1988)

Tags: economic-growth

I read the Lucas paper https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=227120
I don't get the equations 35-36 on change in terms of trade due to change in endowments. Can anyone explain?

[image]

Comment: you'll probably get more responses if you point to a link that contains a free version of the paper, assuming there is one ?  Sometimes, if there isn't one,  I email the author directly and ask for a free version if he can spare one. I'm zero for one when emailing the author of that paper.

Comment: @markleeds thanks, I added the new open version.

Comment: Vu Tuan: For me to have any hope of following that ( Lucas is one of the clearer writers in macro ), I'd have to start from the beginning and I don't have time right now. Hopefully someone with the time or previous background ( so they can jump right into the pages you mentioned ), can help you.